# SQL query times out after switching to view

Tags: sql-server, performance, view

I don't know why I am getting time out after switching to use view. Maybe if I post it here there's something silly I missed.

```
    CREATE VIEW myview as 
        select isnull(t1.col1, t2.col1) as col1
        ,isnull(t1.col2, t2.col2) as col2
        ,isnull(t1.col3, t2.col3) as col3
...(20 lines of similar isnull() calls)
        FROM table1 t1
        JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
        LEFT JOIN sub_view sv3 on sv3.id = t2.id
        LEFT JOIN table4 t4 on t4.id = t2.table_1_fk
```

I am guessing maybe it's the way the view is being used which causes it to time out due to size of the Cartesian product? It goes like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM myview v
JOIN table2 t2 on t2.id = v.id
JOIN table5 t5 on t5.id = v.t5_fk
JOIN table5 t5_2 on t5_2.id = v.f5_fk2
```

The fact I observed is that if I don't use the View, and use the base table directly, which itself yields more record count than the View, there is no time out. So I know that view is somehow the culprit... I went through the Create View documentation on MSDN but there is no useful information. What am I missing about views? Will it help if i add an index to it? Or Should I try to move away from it to use UDF or stored procedure?

```
    table sizes: 
(referred inside the view) 
    table1 10,000 
    table2 120,000 
    subview3 7,000 
    running the view produces 2,000 count
    
    (referred outside the view) 
    table5 26,000
```

Comment: I suggest looking at the Actual Execution Plan (so it includes estimates vs actual numbers) and look out for a Nested Loop Join to myview (or more specifically, what is included in myview). I've found that using views within views can confuse the query optimiser - it can run the view 1 time for each row returned. Other than re-writing the whole thing, one potential fix (within, say, a stored procedure) is to save the data from the view in a temp table (e.g., `SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM myview`), then use that temp table in the next part.

Comment: @seanb thank you for your response. I am programming to an enterprise CMS. Their view I referred to already has 2 levels. My view is the 3rd. Do you think I am emulate their nested view with a CTE expression in my view, thus flattening it. Or do you think temp table can achieve better result?

Comment: Some RDBS do treat CTEs as separate commands (and run them independently) but SQL Server doesn't - it treats it very similar to a sub-query. A CTE *may* work - you can try it - but for reliable results I find a temp table is more reliable. (Note by temp table I mean `CREATE TABLE #...` rather than a table variable, as table variables can have further cardinality issues). You can also try forcing the type of join (e.g., `INNER HASH JOIN`) so that it doesn't do nested loops - but this can also lead to further issues when HASH JOIN isn't the best.

Comment: "The fact I observed is that if I don't use the View, and use the base table directly, which itself yields more record count than the View, there is no time out." - Are you asking us why two different queries take different amounts of time to execute? First, make sure you are getting the same number of records in both cases.